# how to generalize/get base directory for Linux path for python script

Tags: python

(Linux)in Bash I can use variableName= cd $BASEDIR./Desktop to replace HOME/userName/Destop.  How can I achieve the same in Python?

EXAMPLE:
        need to replace home/name to be generic so that I can run this from multiple hosts.
    f = open("home/name/directory/subdirectory/file.cfg", "r")

Comment: The `variableName= ` has no effect in bash, and doesn't change anything about `HOME/userName/Destop`. Please stat what you want to do: do you want to expand `$HOME`/`~`? do you want to set a variable depending on an environment variable? Do you want to change the current directory?

Comment: I am opening and reading in files like so: f = open("home/name/directory/subdirectory/file.cfg", "r") trying to get rid of that /home/name part of the path so that my script can be run on multiple linux machines! How would I add your commands.getoutput("cd $BASEDIR./Desktop") to that example!

Answer (score 1):

You might get some use out of [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) or [`os.path.expandvars`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
'/home/userName/Desktop'
```

or, assuming that `$BASEDIR` is defined in your environment,

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.expandvars('$BASEDIR/Desktop')
'/home/userName/Desktop'
```

Using the first option, maybe you can do what you want to do with:

```
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/directory/subdirectory/file.cfg"), "r")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read environment variables directly from `os.environ`:

```
import os
basedir = os.environ.get('BASEDIR')
```

To construct a path reliably, the `os` module provides `os.path.join`. You should also provide a fallback if the variable is undefined. This could look like this:

```
import os
my_path = os.path.expanduser(os.path.join(
    os.environ.get('BASEDIR', '~'),  # default to HOME
    'Desktop'
)
```

Note that environment variables may not be the most ideal solution. Have a look at arguments, for example via the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use commands libray.

```
import commands

commands.getoutput("cd $BASEDIR./Desktop")
```

Comment: this would be a better answer if you stated that it has been removed in `python3`

Comment: Actually you didn't mention that you are working on python3.x.

Comment: Thanks Harv for the reply, I am new to scripting in general so pardon the newb questions.   So i am opening and reading in files like so:

     f = open("home/name/directory/subdirectory/file.cfg", "r")
trying to get rid of that /home/name part of the path so that my script can be run on multiple linux machines!

How would I add your commands.getoutput("cd $BASEDIR./Desktop") to that example!

Thank you!